# FireAndForget call to WebApi from Azure Function

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I want to be able to call an HTTP endpoint (that I own) from an Azure Function at the end of the Azure Function request.

1. I do not need to know the result of the request
2. If there is a problem in the HTTP endpoint that is called I will log it there
3. I do not want to hold up the return to the client calling the initial Azure Function
4. Offloading the call of the secondary WebApi onto a background job queue is considered overkill for this requirement

Do I simply call HttpClient.PutAsync without an await?

I realise that the dependencies I have used up until the point that the call is made may well not be available when the call returns. Is there a safe way to check if they are?

Comment: `If there is a problem in the HTTP endpoint that is called I will log it there` - assuming it actually gets there...

Comment: The likelihood of it not getting there is so small that I can live with that too (at this point you might be thinking why bother with this call at all :-))

Comment: I am curious about what your http endpoint is going to do. Maybe application insights would be an idea if this is sort of traffic logging. Maybe a pull pattern and an azure queue  would be an idea.

Comment: I will add some info to the questions fior background. Essentially it is an end point that is bascially "Hey someone justy input X their score may have changed. If it has, update it in the DB and end them a Push Notifcation". There is very little reason that will fail. If it does that is not considered a concern. The "score" is not a real time thing and is check on app start anyway and has auto calc after a set period any

Comment: @StephenCleary in case anyone wants to say "i told you so", :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648648/azure-function-app-intermittently-returning-502-bad-gateway/75682325#answer-75682325

Answer (score 0):

My answer may cause some controversy but, you can always start a background task and execute it that way.

For anyone reading this answer, this is far from recommended.  The OP has been very clear that they don't care about exceptions or understanding what sort of result the request is returning ...

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        await httpClient.PutAsync(...);
    }
});
```

If you want to ensure that the call has fired, it may be worth waiting for a second or two after the call is made to ensure it's actually on it's way.

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

If you're worried about dependencies in the call, be sure to construct your payload (i.e. serialise it, etc.) external to the `Task.Run`, basically, minimise any work the background task does.

Comment: I'm adding a comment to this answer as the OP of the question. Whislt this approach does work it is not without it's pitfalls. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648648/azure-function-app-intermittently-returning-502-bad-gateway/75682325#answer-75682325

Comment: So what did you end up doing?!!

Comment: I just sucked up the extra time and I now wait for the response in the same one would for any other web call.