# Azure function app intermittently returning 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Our Azure Fuction has started to return 502 Bad Gateways but not on all calls. I didn't use the word "intermittently" because it is always on the same type of call but now always with the same data.

General Config

- OS in Azure: Windows
- Azure Functions Runtime: 3
- App Service Plan: Consumption

The API exposed by the AF is pretty simple

1. GET myazure.com/api/v1/entityid?quantity=1 will return a new entity id
2. PUT myazure.com/api/v1/{modelName},the body contains the model as JSON
3. GET myazure.com/api/v1/{modelName}/{entityIdFromStep1} will return the model added in step 2
4. DELETE myazure.com/api/v1/{modelName} the body contains the model that was added in step 2. This endpoint can take an array of models and will delete all of them

We have a TEST script of 1200 calls that tries to add,check and delete all our models and various error scenarios. These tests are run using Postman and are run in Azure Dev Ops although the issue is still seen if i run from local Postman Agent.
The call that returns the 502 is the GET, sometimes it is the first time it is called but other times it is the third or fourth.

I made some changes to the AF in preparation for moving to function runtime 4. They were arounnd Dependency Injection and moving from static methods in the Function to non-static.

During the test run I do see entries in App Insights but never for the call that returns the 502.

If I run the tests against the code that was lastr pushed to production these 502s do not happen

Comment: Is there something running in front of the function like Azure Application Gateway, Front Door or APIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR;

This was down to a combination of two errors

1. Misconfiguring one of the AF's Application settings which meant that the AF was trying to create a System.Uri with an invalid uri
2. An attempt at a cheap and dirty Fire and Forget as discussed in this SO question, [FireAndForget call to WebApi from Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326799/fireandforget-call-to-webapi-from-azure-function)

In more detail

We wanted to call a WebApi at the end of processing in one of the functions. The base uri for that api needed to be configurable and in the service I was reading from config and building a System.Uri

```
string azureAdClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd__ClientId", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
string azureAdInstance = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd__Instance", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
string azureAdTenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd__TenantId", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
string azureAdClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd__ClientSecret", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

string uri = $"{azureAdInstance}{azureAdTenantId}/";
Uri authorityUri = new System.Uri(uri);

var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(azureAdClientId)
                                    .WithClientSecret(azureAdClientSecret)
                                    .WithAuthority(authorityUri)
                                    .Build();
```

The "AzureAd__Instance" setting was incorrectly named in our ARM template so azureAdInstance was null meaning that `uri` when passed to the System.Uri was invalid and would throw an exception.

Under normal circumstances this exception would have been caught and logged and I would have fixed the issue relatively quickly.

However I was calling the WebApi with a Fire & Forget approach and to do that I was abusing the async/await functionality and calling the following method without bothering to await it. Note the async but no Task return and it's not being awaited.

```
public async void RequestSignalRecalc(Guid patientId, string clientTzo)
{
    await this.PrepareAuthenticatedClient();

    dynamic bodyObject = new ExpandoObject();
    bodyObject.clientTZO = clientTzo;
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject);
    StringContent bodyContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    Task task = this.httpClient.PutAsync($"{this.signalApiBaseAddress}v1/patients/{patientId}/recalc", bodyContent);
}
```

I was told that was a dumb idea by people much smarter than me but i did it anyway, see comments on [FireAndForget call to WebApi from Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326799/fireandforget-call-to-webapi-from-azure-function#comment132921687_75326799)

As mentioned in the question part there were no logs in Appinsights when the calls failed with a 502 making it hard to diagnose. I finally found some logging via the Kudu tools in Azure Portal. See the Advanced Tools -> Tools -> Diagnostic Dump. That gave me a zip file that included eventlog.xml. That showed the following event (I've trimmed out most of it)

> 1032 CoreCLR Version: 4.700.22.55902 .NET Core
> Version: 3.1.32 Description: The process was terminated due to an
> unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.UriFormatException:
> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.    at
> System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)    [OurCode]    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1(Object
> state)    at
> System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback
> quwi)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext
> executionContext, Action`1 callback, TState& state)    at
> System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()    at
> System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
> System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

The key parts are the Exception info, the call stack and the line "**The process was terminated**" I'm assuming that this was the reason i was never getting my logs written to App Insights. I don't know why it causes a 502 but I have stopped trying to do the cheap and dirty fire and forget.

Moral of the story is if smart experienced people are suggesting what you are doing is a bad idea, seriously consider not doing it :-)