# Random 404 and 502 errors on Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Experiencing a very strange issue in production for Azure Functions. HTTP triggers suddenly (no inciting event that I can identify, no recent deployments or configuration changes) are intermittently returning 404 and 502 errors. Sometimes it works correctly, but more often than not it responds with either a 404 or a 502 error.

We are using the 3.x function runtime, which I know is deprecated currently, but this just suddenly started happening today.

I've tried redeploying, changing https settings, no luck.

Any help as to what might be the cause, and what to do about it?

The closest thing I could find similar to this is [Azure function app intermittently returning 502 Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648648/azure-function-app-intermittently-returning-502-bad-gateway), but that cause doesn't seem to apply here.

EDIT: After working through this with Microsoft Support, the consensus seems to be that this was caused by a faulty worker. Their recommendation was to change the service tier of the function app for an hour to have a new worker assigned. I ended up just making an entirely new function app and using that, which hasn't had any of the errors.

Comment: Is there anything in front like an Application Gateway, APIM or Front Door?

Comment: @PeterBons No, nothing in front of the Azure Function App. I'm very confused as to why http calls sometimes work with 200 OK, but the same call can return 404 or 502. I don't even know how to begin debugging this.

Comment: @KalZekdor, Occurences such as this on the cloud usually means that there are changes being made, and as you said its deprecated, maybe you can move up to the latest function runtime? (I have seen this before when an update has been made to a service). When it starts happening doesnt matter, since we cannot know what development progress was being made on the backend.

Comment: Besides these, you can check if your function is running to high CPU, RAM. Make sure you are not getting throttled and hitting some sort of limit. If nothing fixes it, you can enable verbose logging in your function, and share the full error messages here, would be easier to troubleshoot. But as I said above, it could be a change deployed on the backend, may not be related to anything recent you have done.

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas Working on updating to the latest runtime, but there's a lot of changes that need to be made. I'll look to see about getting some verbose logs, if you could point me in the direction of some guides to get the sort of error messages which would be helpful, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @KalZekdor I will post it as an answer since its long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Application Insights resource and enable it:

[image]

Under Settings of your Function app as below then click on view insights data, this will take you to the dashboard where you see detailed information about your function:

[image]

Now in this dashboard you can either connect to log analytics from here, under 'Monitor' tab and then 'Logs', or you can add a Diagnostic Setting under the functions 'Monitoring' Tab

[image]

For more details, use documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp

Note: Log analytics uses Kusto query language, so you might need to get used to it, but its easy to learn if you want to. Since a lot of applications logs can be queried in Azure with it.

Comment: I have Application Insights configured here, but to the best of my knowledge the requests that are getting 404 or 502 are not logged here. I only see the requests which are successfully received with a 200 OK.

Comment: @KalZekdor Make sure your logs are at 'Debug' or 'Information' level and not 'Warning' or less. Since information and above are the verbose ones. Also check the activity log of your function app and see if its logged there (it should be if its configured)

Comment: Haven't been able to get any more detailed logs, but I can confirm that the 404 and 502 errors occur on the default function homepage, not just on http triggers.

Comment: @KalZekdor, do share the detailed error message once you find it. I can be able to at least get you in the right direction. However, this is actually an issue for the support team of the Function App. Make sure to open a ticket with them as well. As it could be anything from a service outage... to all sorts of things such as some new feature being enabled that is causing this.

Comment: Always good advice. I have an open ticket with the support team, still waiting to hear back. I've gotten a little bit closer to what's happening, some instances are occasionally becoming entirely unresponsive, not clear why. But they're not actually accepting the request, hence no detailed logs. I've set up some aggressive pruning of unresponsive instances, which has helped somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The support team believes this was caused by a faulty worker. A new function app with a fresh deployment from the same codebase has not experienced any of the errors. I'm marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: @KalZekdor, As I guessed it was something on the backend :) , usually when it happens without any explanation or any recent changes, I start looking that way. Anyways, glad you are good now.